# Automatically import one header into each project .m file in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have logger.h file with static logger class. Then I want to add log messages to into each method invocation to trace app execution.

In order to do that I have to include logger.h into almost each Xcode .m project file. Is there any way to tell Xcode to automatically import logger.h into each project's .m file.

thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could put the `#include` directive in your prefix header, effectively importing it across your project.